# Why does count++ not work when being passed as an argument

Tags: javascript, arguments, increment

I have the code below. If you pass the code a list, it will provide the value in that position (it is zero-indexed). This code works, but if I replace **count = count + 1** with **count++** (in the last branch on the conditional), it no longer works. Can someone help me understand why?

Note: If you call the function like this:

```
var list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 10, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}}

nth(list, 1)
```

The output should be 20.

```
function nth(list, index, count) {
    if (count === undefined) {
        count = 0;
    }

    if (count === index) {
        return list.value;
    }
    else if (list.rest === null) {
        return undefined;
    }
    else {
        // note that count++ will not work here
        return nth(list.rest, index, count = count + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `20` in your `list`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because

```
 count++
```

Is a postfix increment. That means it creates a new value, the old count, and passes that value into the function.

You want prefix.

```
 ++count.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
return nth(list.rest, index, count = count + 1);
```

to

```
return nth(list.rest, index, ++count);
```